# page not opening inside iframe content window

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have an HTML Page and inside this HTML page, i have iframe content. Below is the sample code. Problem is the if I click the link "Term" which has "href" tag which is dynamically updated through javascript code. Problem is the  page instead of opening inside the frame it opens in  a separate window Any help or suggestions would be more  helpful

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="frmIndex">

      <li class="enc-terms-selected">
        <a id="encodedTermsListinghref" href="#" target="icontentFrame" title="Terms">
          <i class="fa fa-file-code-o fa-menu-item"></i><span>Terms</span></a>
      </li>

      <!-- Main Content -->
      <div id="page-content-wrapper" class="section_padding_top_50 section_padding_bottom_50 columns_padding_0">
        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="row dsg-iframe-pos">
          <div id="divMainContent" class="col-sm-10 col-med-10 col-lg-10">
            <iframe src="" id="icontentFrame" class="iframe"></iframe>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <script>
        $('#encodedTermsListinghref', window.parent.document).attr('href', "http://www.google.com")

      </script>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

`<iframe src="" id="icontentFrame" class="iframe"></iframe>`

There should be:

`<iframe src="" name="icontentFrame" class="iframe"></iframe>`

It's explained here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_name.asp